# A simple example for TBB

Tags: c++, tbb

I'm trying to get into Threading Building Blocks but I can't get over the wall of errors that I'm getting.

What I'm trying to do in this case is to show that multithreading is better when trying to find a prime number. How can I paralellize the while loop with parallel_for?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int i){
     for(int k=2;k<=i/2;k++)if(i%k==0)return 0;
     return 1;
     }

int main(){
    clock_t t1,t2;
    t1 = clock();
    int counter = 0;
    int number = 2;
    int limit;

    cout << "Input which prime you want: ";
    cin >> limit;

    while(true){
        if(isPrime(number))counter++;
        if(counter == limit)break;
        number++;
    }

    t2 = clock();
    double timeElapsed = ((double) t2 - (double) t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << limit << "-nth prime is " << number << endl;
    cout << "Time time elapsed: " << timeElapsed << " s." << endl;
}
```

Comment: did you read the manual? as an example it has a prime number finder program. https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/de/4d/Introduce_Parallelism.pdf

Comment: I spent most of my weekend searching for something like that and I just couldn't find it. Thanks a lot. I'll answer my question once I read it.